# preg_match_all for two words, allowing chars in the middle

Tags: php, regex, pattern-matching

what I'm trying to do is, given a string such as

```
trying to download some music, give me the details to download the music
```

get a matching result through preg_match_all that would give me something like

```
[0][0] => download some music
[0][1] => some
[1][0] => download the music
[1][1] => the
```

but I'm not able to achieve this. I'm using this pattern

```
§download(.*)music(.*)§
```

but the problem is that it just matches the first `download` (the one from `download some music`) and the last `music` (the one from `download the music`), while **my goal is to find all occurrences and get the chars in between the two words** (it should actually work for any number of words, but let's start with two).

Any help is appreciated, thanks! :)

> **UPDATE**: After having the issue solved, I wrote an article on how this kind of regex can be used to make a *gentle pattern match* (or, rather, to compute pattern relevance in a given text): http://www.thecrowned.org/method-for-pattern-relevance-in-text

Comment: So you're saying the regex is too "*greedy*"?

Comment: `download\s*\b(.*?)\b\s*music\b`

Comment: Yes, that's the idea... The idea is that it should find `download` and then look for `music` just after it, as soon as it can find it, without matching everything in the middle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
\bdownload\b(.*?)\bmusic\b

              ^^
```

Do a `non greedy` search.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/fM9lY3/29

```
$re = "/\\bdownload\\b(.*?)\\bmusic\\b/"; 
$str = "trying to download some music, give me the details to download the music"; 

preg_match_all($re, $str, $matches);
```

Comment: I've written an article on computing how much a string is relevant for a given text which uses this regex http://www.thecrowned.org/method-for-pattern-relevance-in-text, may be useful :)